# failed to json.marshal map with non string keys

Tags: json, go

I want to convert a `map[int]string` to `json`, so I thought `json.Marshal()` would do the trick, but it fails saying unsupported type `map[int]string`. But whereas if I use a `map` with key string it works fine.

http://play.golang.org/p/qhlS9Nt8qQ

Later on inspection of the marshaller code, there is an explicit check to see if the key is not string and returns `UnsupportedTypeError`...

Why can't I even use primitives as keys? If json standard doesn't allow non string keys, shouldn't `json.Marshal` convert the primitives to string and use them as keys ?

Comment: It states as much in the package docs: "Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must be string; the object keys are used directly as map keys". http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not because of Go, but because of Json: Json does not support anything else than strings for keys.

Have a look a the grammar of Json:

```
pair
    string : value
string
    ""
    " chars "
```

The full grammar is available on the [Json website](http://www.json.org/).

Unfortunately, to use integers as keys, you must convert them to string beforehand, for instance using `strconv.Itoa`: it is not up to the `json` package to do this work.

Comment: Seems like the newer versions of go support non string keys. "Map values encode as JSON objects. The map's key type must either be a string, an integer type, or implement encoding.TextMarshaler."